# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2935848, 2935849]

Tags: python, testing, scikit-learn, split, train-test-split

When I run this code:

```
feature_names = ["date","shop_id", "item_id", "item_price", "item_cnt_day"]
feature_names

X_train = train[feature_names]
print(X_train.shape)
X_train.head()

X_sales = sales[feature_names]
print(X_sales.shape)
X_sales.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

X_train, X_sales, y_train, y_sales = train_test_split(X_train, X_sales, test_size=0.3)


feature_names = ["date","shop_id", "item_id", "item_price", "item_cnt_day"]
feature_names
​
X_train = train[feature_names]
print(X_train.shape)
X_train.head()
​
X_sales = sales[feature_names]
print(X_sales.shape)
X_sales.head()
​
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
​
X_train, X_sales, y_train, y_sales = train_test_split(X_train, X_sales, test_size=0.3)
​
(2935848, 5)
(2935849, 5)
```

I get this `ValueError`:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 13 from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
> 14
> ---> 15 X_train, X_sales, y_train, y_sales = train_test_split(X_train, X_sales, test_size=0.3)
> 16
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/aiffel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py
> in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)    2125         raise
> TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))    2126
> -> 2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)    2128     2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/aiffel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> in indexable(*iterables)
> 291     """
> 292     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
> --> 293     check_consistent_length(*result)
> 294     return result
> 295
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/aiffel/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
> in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
> 255     if len(uniques) > 1:
> 256         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
> --> 257                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
> 258
> 259
>
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2935848, 2935849]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is reached because you two dataframe (train and sales) have different length. Your train dataset has 2935848 samples and the sales dataset has 2935849. **Both dataset has to have the same length in order to work properly**. Check why this length is not matching and add one row or drop one to match them.

Secondly, but no least, you should understand what are you doing with `train_test_split` and which is your goal. This function inputs are X and Y, and outputs `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, `y_test`. Reading your code, you are inputting two X (`X_train` and `X_sales`) with same 5 features. I hope you are doing this because some reason, be aware of this.

X are all the samples with their features, and Y are the corresponding outputs value you want to predict. Check that and evaluate is using `train_test_split` is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error while I'm trying to do my confusion matrix:
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1527, 1]

This is my code:

```
x = df[['gender', 'age', 'hypertension', 'ever_married', 'work_type', 'Residence_type', 'avg_glucose_level', 'bmi', 'smoking_status', 'work_type_cat', 'gender_cat', 'Residence_type_cat']]
y = df['stroke']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=20)
print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train_scale = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_scale = scaler.fit_transform(x_test)

KNN = KNeighborsClassifier()
x = df[['gender', 'age', 'hypertension', 'heart_disease', 'ever_married', 'work_type', 'Residence_type', 'avg_glucose_level', 'bmi', 'smoking_status', 'work_type_cat', 'gender_cat', 'Residence_type_cat']]
y = df['stroke']
print(x.head())
print(y.head())
KNN = KNN.fit(x, y)
test = pd.DataFrame()
test['gender'] = [2]
test['age'] = [3]
test['hypertension'] = [0]
test['heart_disease'] = [0]
test['ever_married'] = [2]
test['work_type'] = [4]
test['Residence_type'] = [2]
test['avg_glucose_level'] = [95.12]
test['bmi'] = [18]
test['smoking_status'] = [2]
test['work_type_cat'] = [4]
test['gender_cat'] = [1]
test['Residence_type_cat'] = [1]
y_predict = KNN.predict(test)

print(y_predict)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict))
```